# How to get the name of the report loaded inside the asp.net reportviewer control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am using `ReportViewer` control in my asp.net web application.

There is a button called **View Report**, the following code is in the asp.net button `Click` event which loads the report. The parameters are selected on the web page 
and passed on to `ReportViewer` control as shown below. This works fine.

```
rptvw.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
rptvw.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:90/reportserver");
rptvw.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Reports/Dashboard1";

var param = new ReportParameter[2];
param[0] = new ReportParameter("Parameter1", dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text))
param[1] = new ReportParameter("Parameter2", dropdownlist2.SelectedItem.Text));
rptvw.ServerReport.SetParameters(param);
rptvw.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

I have 3 separate reports (.rdl files) for example `Dashboard2`, `Dasboard3` and `Dashboard4`. 
On `Dashboard1` (.rdl file) report there are `actions`, *links*, when clicked it loads `Dashboard2`, `Dashboard3` and 4 reports.

My problem is how can the web page know which report is loaded so that I can apply the relevant parameters when **View Report** button is clicked and display the respective report?

Which `ReportViewer` web control eventcan I use to determine which report is loaded?

Comment: so you have create sub report and set parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. I have created another report Dashboard2 which opens up when a link is clicked on Dashboard1 and the parameters from Dashboard1 are passed to the Dashboard2. But the Idea is to change the parameters from the Web page rather than on Dashboard2 report. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

What I feel from your question and the code that you have supplied is that
this **View Report** button click will always show the **Dashboard1** report and upon clicking the links you will display other related reports. So parameters are supposed to be passed from **this** report where you click the link and **not** from the web-page.
You can check [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519554%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information. 
So there should actually be no question of passing the values to parameters from web-page when you clicking somewhere else.

HTH